# embed srt into mp4/m4v

Tags: video, subtitles, mp4, m4v, multiplexing

i have an converted .mp4 video file (or .m4v) + an `.srt` file.

Is there a way for me to embed this `.srt` file into that mp4 file without running a complete convertion?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is generally called muxing or re-muxing.

Have a look at [Subler](http://code.google.com/p/subler/), it should be able to do what you want. Open your video file, then drag the srt onto the screen and save as new file.

Comment: "Subler is an Mac OS X app created to mux mp4 files..." Just a note for anyone out there reading the thread who's not on a Mac (and since OP never mentioned/tagged an OS)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want incrusted subtitles (included in the video stream), you can use `mkvmerge GUI`, which will allow you to merge in one `mkv` file all the subtitles, audio tracks and video tracks you want.

It seems to be distributed under the name `mkvtoolnix` for Windows (available for Ubuntu/Debian with the package `mkvtoolnix` from `deb-multimedia`).