# Is there a way to soft embed subtitles into an mp4 file without re-encoding?

Tags: linux, mp4, subtitles

I am trying to add an `srt` file(s) to `mp4` files. Is there a way to do it without re-encoding the file.

What I have tried:

- Added subtitles with the handbrake-cli. While this technically worked, it obliterated the quality of the video and took a long time to re-encode the file
- I tried an `ffmpeg` approach as found on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584272), but I apparently dont have the `mov_text` codec and [no one else seems to either](https://www.google.com/search?q=install+mov_text+codec)

There is another [SuperUser Answer](https://superuser.com/a/291923/82946) which suggests that I may need to look for a *muxer*. But that answer pertains to Mac OS only.

Comment: With VLC you could play your mp4 with srt subtitles while saving the resulting output stream to another file. That's practically re-encoding, though.

Comment: What OS are you using? I mean, what distro & what version.

Comment: @pepoluan I am using an ubuntu saucy release at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading the **static build** of ffmpeg from their download site: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Note, though, that mov_text seems to be a hit-and-miss situation; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. You might have much better results re-muxing into a matroska container (.mkv), and play it using VLC.

Comment: OK, that did it!... great suggestion. To clarify what I did for posterity: I downloaded a newer build, 64-bit version of `ffmpeg` from [http://ffmpeg.org/download.html](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Once on my machine I ran the command found at this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17584272/705055) referencing the newly acquired version of `ffmpeg`. The command did its thing, and the outcome was a new `mp4` with perfect subtitles.

Comment: @Hari thanks for the clarification; great to hear that it works :-) ... happy subtitling!

Answer (score 5):

As [explained by @axel_c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7980/66295), you could use [mkvmerge](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html) to create a [Matroska container](http://www.matroska.org/) and include the subtitles in the output:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv video.mp4 subtitles.srt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to embed subtitles (rather than burn) then try a free GPL software called Video Updater Tools.

It uses other tools behind the scene (like ffmpeg, mkvmerge, mp4box etc) but packaged nicely into a GUI and CLI. It works on directories recursively so you can completely automate the entire process. You can drag and drop files/folder in the GUI version or use the CLI for scripting.

It can embed SRT subtitles (and chapters from EDL) in MP4/M4V/MKV containers from EDL and SRT files.

(It can also extract subtitles from most container formats if required)

You can download it at:
https://videoupdatertools.codeplex.com